# Dynamically choose which SSIS packages to launch

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Having different set of tables for every SSIS load, I want to implement a smart routine which would launch only the packages which files are present.
I have a task that uploads file listing from a folder to a database table:

[dbo].[FileList]

1. Product.csv
2. Sales_2018.csv
3. Customer.csv
4. Delivery.csv

If in my SSIS, besides Product, Sales, Customer, Delivery packages I also have Shipping, Returns and others, is it possible to disable those automatically based on FileList match. So only Product, Sales, Customer, Delivery packages would run?

Or should it be approached in a different way?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Assign the value of the package to run in a variable, and then you can refer to the variable as the name of the SSIS package to run in the Execute Package Task. You'll need to set the value of Package Name in the Expression property in the properties pane, and don't forget to include the extension of the package (probably `dtsx`) in its name.

Comment: Thank you.
What I did so far:
1) Execute SQL Task with 
SELECT ? + 'dtsx' = [file] FROM SANDBOX.dbo.FileList
with Variable Name of PackageToRun with Output Direction
2) Execute Package Task with
Parameter bindings: NewParameterName = User::PackageToRun
Expressions: PackageName @[User::PackageToRun]

On Package tab I choose Package.dtsx in the dropdown and it shows a red cross button...

I have a table populated as well as a number of disconnected packages with the same names in SSIS.

What do I miss?

Comment: The error is saying the package is not specified...

Comment: You won't need to select the package name on the Execute Package Task; it'll be set by the expression. Changing it's value would remove the expression.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past using this simple control flow.

Note the 2nd for each only loops through one time. It is just a check to see if the one file exists without a script task.

[image]

A few more notes:

```
1. Store execute sql results into Object Variable
2. Outer foreach is on ADO Object (variable from step 1)
2a. Map the current iteration of the object to local variables
3. Inner foreach is on file based on local variable from step 2
4. Package expression is based on local variable from step 2
```

Comment: how about data connectors? Do you also set up variables for them?
I do have mapping table for paths and filenames.

Comment: You need both filepathName and package Name stored in the table. With those, you can search to see if the file exists and if so, run the package.

Comment: filePathName will be an expression on the foreach file search. And packagename an expression on Run Package

Comment: Note the inner foreach is only there to check if the file exists. I find this easier to explain to others rather than using a script task where you set a Boolean variable to System.IO.File.Exists(filePathName);